# Listview containing edittext

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext, android-arrayadapter

I have a **listview** and its rows are **composed of some edittexts**. My **problem** is that its **value is  automatically changing while scrolling**. I have tried many methods but none of them works. Is there any example related to this? Anyone please help me

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ListView myList;
private CustomAdapter myAdapter;
Context context;
private String[] guess = new String[20];

ArrayList<String> list_id = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    for(int i=0;i<19;i++){
        list_id.add(""+i);
        guess[i] = i+"";
    }

    myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    myList.setItemsCanFocus(true);

    initList();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
public void initList()
{
    ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.id.textView1, guess)
    {

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            if (convertView == null)
            {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            }

            final String theData = getItem(position);
            final EditText editText = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            //editText.setText(theData);
            editText.setText(guess[position]);
            editText.addTextChangedListener(
                    new MyTextWatcher(position)
                    );

            return convertView;
        }
        };

        myList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}

class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
    private int position;

    public MyTextWatcher(int position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        guess[position] = s.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    // other methods are created, but empty
}

}
```

Comment: post the code what you had tried so that you will get the issues fixed.

Comment: put **if-else** in `getView()` of adapter which set to value to edittext if available else just set empty text.

Comment: Still its not working :(

Comment: Will you always have 20 rows? If so, maybe consider not using a ListView because ListView will recycle rows and it may be difficult to preserve what was in the EditTexts when the rows get recycled.

Comment: No..i just used 20 to test it. It will vary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I fix the problem myself. The problem was because of my xml file. For each row I have used two edittexts, one having inputtype "numberDecimal" and the other "text".There was the problem. When I changed both input type to "NumberDecimal" it worked. I dont know why. And for entering text, I chnaged one of the edittext inputtype to "textvisiblepassword".

Answer (score 0):

create atom_pay_list_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/atomPay_name"
        android:layout_width="0sp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:hint="@string/EnterPays_atomPay_nameHint"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/atomPay_value"
        android:layout_width="0sp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:text="@string/EnterPays_TextView_ZeroValue"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/atomPay_removePay"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/width_button"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/emptyText"
        android:onClick="removeAtomPayOnClickHandler"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Create list item adapter:

```
public class AtomPayListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<AtomPayment> {

    private List<AtomPayment> items;
    private int layoutResourceId;
    private Context context;

    public AtomPayListAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<AtomPayment> items) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, items);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        AtomPaymentHolder holder = null;

        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new AtomPaymentHolder();
        holder.atomPayment = items.get(position);
        holder.removePaymentButton = (ImageButton)row.findViewById(R.id.atomPay_removePay);
        holder.removePaymentButton.setTag(holder.atomPayment);

        holder.name = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.atomPay_name);
        holder.value = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.atomPay_value);

        row.setTag(holder);

        setupItem(holder);
        return row;
    }

    private void setupItem(AtomPaymentHolder holder) {
        holder.name.setText(holder.atomPayment.getName());
        holder.value.setText(String.valueOf(holder.atomPayment.getValue()));
    }

    public static class AtomPaymentHolder {
        AtomPayment atomPayment;
        TextView name;
        TextView value;
        ImageButton removePaymentButton;
    }
}
```

add ListView in your activity layout xml file:

You can use [THIS](http://looksok.wordpress.com/2012/11/03/android-custom-listview-tutorial/) OR [THIS](http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/android-focusable-edittext-inside-listview/) to do this.

Comment: Error in that code too..i can't type anything on that edittexts. Actually its work once and after adding more rows, its not working. (The problem arises when i removed softkeyboard and then click on that edittext)

Comment: use tutorial links:http://looksok.wordpress.com/2012/11/03/android-custom-listview-tutorial/ OR http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/android-focusable-edittext-inside-listview/